# IE fires the change event for a checkbox when the user clicks anywhere on the screen

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Here is the simplest code that recreates the problem.  (In my real world example, I'm resetting the checkbox if there is an error with an ajax call.)

```
<html>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function(){
        $('#ckbx').change( function( e ){
            alert('fired.');
            this.checked = !this.checked;
        })
    });
</script>

<form>
    <input id="ckbx" type="checkbox"></input>
</form>

</html>
```

In IE9, when I click the checkbox, it displays the alert.  Then if I wait any amount of time, then click anywhere else on the page, it fires the event again.

If I remove `this.checked = !this.checked` the problem goes away.

Can anyone explain this to me?  Or provide a way to get around this problem?

**UPDATE:**
I'm using jquery 1.4.2; in jquery 1.6 this is not a problem.  However, we are close to releasing, and we are reluctant to change versions of jquery.

Comment: jQuery has been updated for IE9.  Since you found an old jQuery bug specific to IE9 and fixed in jQuery 1.6, I'm not sure what you want from us.

Comment: It does it for me in IE7 even with jQuery 1.6.2, so I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: 'Khm'!.....Did I heard 'IE'? :)

Comment: @sparky672 I need a work around for jQuery 1.4.2 as that is the version that we are locked into for now.  One of the todo for the next release is upgrading JQuery.  However, if we upgraded jQuery now, we would have to redo a lot of testing, and we don't want to put the effort forth for that at this point.

Comment: @mlsteeves: I totally understand why you believe you're locked into 1.4.2 for now.  My only point is that **IF** it's indeed an IE 9 specific bug only with jQuery older than 1.6, then the fix seems obvious no matter how bitter.

Comment: @Sparky672 Just because using 1.6 instead of 1.4.2 fixes the problem, doesn't mean there isn't another way around the problem.  If spending 4h on this comes up with a solution that can save days of testing, then it certainly is worth it.

Comment: @mlsteeves:  Did I say there was no possibility for another solution?  See answers below... not sure if they work since you have not yet commented on them.

Comment: @Sparky672 You said, "I'm not sure what you want from us."  I'm just trying to clarify what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `.change()` event is firing again when you reset the checkbox and click elsewhere on the page.  You should use the `.click()` event instead.

```
<html>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function(){
        $('#ckbx').click( function( e ){
            alert('fired.');
            this.checked = !this.checked;
        })
    });
</script>

<form>
    <input id="ckbx" type="checkbox"></input>
</form>

</html>
```

Comment: When I read this response, I originally thought that the click wouldn't handle when the user uses the keyboard, but it does.  So, I'm going to go with this solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that you are effectively firing the change event from within the change event. One option could be to use a different event so you can the change the value via code.

Alternatively, you could consider a activeFlag similar to this...

```
var activeFlag;
$(document).ready( function(){
    activeFlag = true;
    $('#ckbx').change( function( e ){
        if(activeFlag)
        {
            alert('fired.');
            activeFlag = false;//temp disable event to process value reset
            this.checked = !this.checked;
            activeFlag = true;
        }
    })
});
```

hope that helps

RE: THE OTHER SUGGESTION

This would be the same as my suggestion to use another event. However, with the click you lose you event handler if the user tabs to and uses the space bar to make the change. Of course, you can decide if this is acceptable or not.

Sorry to the other poster, I would have commented on yours but I don't have the reputation yet. Which is actually why I am here, I want to build it up purely so I can hit 15 and mark up an answer that helped me out the other day. Silly really

Answer (score 1):

The active flag idea seems to have the same problem, though it works if implemented like this:

```
var activeFlag = true;
$('#ckbx').change( function( e ){
    if(activeFlag)
    {
        activeFlag = false;
        alert('fired.');            
        this.checked = !this.checked;           
    }
    else
    {
        activeFlag = true;
    }
})
```